# How to pass output directory folder in testng from command line

Tags: eclipse, testng

TestNG command line argument :
-d  A directory

How do I use this option in eclipse ?

I tried passing it as VM arguments but I get error as unrecognized option

Answer (score 0):

See [TestNG - Eclipse](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html) > [Preferences and Properties](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-preferences).

You can the [TestNG workbench preferences](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-workbench-preferences), the [project preferences](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-project-properties), or a combination of both (so that you can have defaults and then override them in a project as needed):

> **9.1 - Workbench Preferences**
>
> TestNG workbench preferences:
>
> The preferences here are shared among projects and launch configurations.
>
> - **Output directory**: the path where to store the output including temp files, report files, etc. By default, the path is relative to each project except you check the option **Absolute ouput path** below.
>
> ...
>
> **9.2 - Project Properties**
>
> Project level properties:
>
> Here are properties on each project level, it will override the same properties if defined in [TestNG workbench preferences](http://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html#eclipse-workbench-preferences)
>
> - **Output directory**: for example, in the figure above, I prefer to put the output to maven 'target' directory rather than the default one under project root
>
> ...